# Efficient way to build julia array element by element

Tags: arrays, julia

What's the best way to build a Julia array element by element when I am not sure of the final array size? In my problem, I am building the array in a single for loop.

So far, I have figured out I can either push into the array or index into a pre-allocated array:

```
using BenchmarkTools

function push_to_array!(array, N)
    for i in 1:N
        # some computation
        push!(array, rand(Int64))
    end
end

function fill_array!(array, N)
    for i in 1:N
        # some computation
        array[i]=rand(Int64)
    end
end

N = 100_000_000 # unknown in the real problem

empty = Vector{Int64}()
preallocated = Vector{Int64}(undef, 2*N) # 2*N represents some upper bound on N

@btime push_to_array!(empty, N)
#  28.272 s (6 allocations: 0 bytes)
@btime fill_array!(preallocated, N)
#  2.449 s (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

So filling a pre-allocated array is a lot faster than pushing, however, it's a bit cumbersome as I need to trim the output with `correct_size = preallocated[1:N]`.

Is there a faster/better way of doing this?

Comment: If you have a rough idea of the final size, you can use `sizehint!` on the output array before you start pushing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Julia you have views - no trimming required.
Simply do:

```
correct_size = @view preallocated[1:1_000_000]
```

or

```
correct_size = view(preallocated, 1:1_000_000)
```

Now this operation is very cheap (BTW note also that you are not bencharking correctly as `@time` measures both compile time and execution time):

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> @btime correct_size = @view $preallocated[1:1_000_000];
  1.800 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

In conclusion making a `view` is basically free.

Finally, note that you can just `resize!` the array (the time cost is the same as in case of a `@view`):

```
resize!(preallocated, 1_000_000)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I have updated the question with @btime timings. So I take it that the best way to build the array is by preallocating or using `sizehint!` and then using `@view` or `resize!`.

Comment: Btw, what's the dollarsign for in `@view $preallocated`? I couldn't find it in manual.

Comment: The dollar sign `$` is understood by the `@btime` macro - it makes the global variable type stable otherwise we would be measuring unboxing time of it.